# RPC lib for Python

Tags: python, frameworks, rpc

What RPC framework/lib for python could you recommend me? The architecture is client-server, server should stand high load, and connection tunneled over ssl. I've googled such things as pyro, twisted.spread, rpyc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python

Comment: xmlrpc was advised in those discussion but I don't need xmlrpc or soap.

Answer (score 2):

The are some alternatives to Pyro if you really need high loads:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jpc (see more on http://winpdb.org/2009/11/enter-jpc/)
- From the same guy: http://code.google.com/p/rfoo/

Both are really fast. The second one needs Cython, however; so you can try jpc on the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You may like **[rpclib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpclib)** that is good presented in this [lighting talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4zdWLuSbV0#t=21m58) from PyCon 2012.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Joren, linked page won't change.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://rpyc.sourceforge.net/index.html It is very nice micro RPC library with async calls, SSL, etc.