# How can i call a local python function from my remote app server?

Tags: python, sockets, printing, ocx

I have written a python application with an inclusion of an ActiveX control(ocx) to print via serial Port to an Epson receipt printer using the win32com library. It's Ok !!! but my master app in on another server. How can i comunicate with my app locally?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a [Remote procedure call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) framework. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python) for various solutions in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!! I've solved this problem using on my local PC a python module called [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) that include my function and call my ocx component!!