# json-rpc over http in python

Tags: python, http, json-rpc

An old question [What is the current choice for doing RPC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python) gave me a good choice of Python JSON-RPC implementation to choose from:

- [python-symmetric-jsonrpc](http://github.com/niligulmohar/python-symmetric-jsonrpc)
- [rpcbd](http://www.openminddev.net/rpcbd/python/)
- [Ladon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ladon)
- [jsonrpc2-zeromq-python](https://github.com/wiltd/jsonrpc2-zeromq-python)

But the service I want to communicate with works over HTTP. How can I bend of these to work over HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like [jsonrpclib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonrpclib) will json-rpc over http without any trouble.