# Python multiprocessing: Start/stop processes on server

Tags: python, multiprocessing, algorithmic-trading

I am building an algorithmic trading platform using Python. Multiple algorithms are monitoring the market and execute trades accordingly daily from 09:30 to 16:00.

What I'm looking for is to start and stop algorithms arbitrarily from a client. Therefore I want to have a server script running using `multiprocessing` and a client which can start/stop/list algorithms (which should run in separate `process`) at any given time.

Any examples of how this can be done? The majority of online examples are for queue servers, which do not seem to fit my problem.

**EDIT:**

I am trying to to this with the package `multiprocessing`. The idea of using a queue seems wrong to me, as I know an arbitrary number of processes will for a fact run for the whole day or at least until I say stop. I'm not trying to run a short script and let a worker consume the next job from a queue once the previous is done. Actually I'm thinking of having a server script using a `Manager` which will run forever and just start new scripts in separate processes/threads when requested. I would however, like to be able to send a stop signal to a process to kill it. I do have a feeling that I'm doing this kinda backwards :-) What I have is:

**server.py:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from time import strftime


class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, port=50000, authkey=''):
        self.processes = {}
        self._authkey = authkey
        self.port = port
        self.server = None
        self.running = False
        BaseManager.register('get_process', callable=lambda: self)


    def start_server(self):
        manager = BaseManager(address=('', self.port), authkey=self._authkey)
        self.server = manager.get_server()
        try:
            self._logmessage("Server started")
            self.running = True
            self.server.serve_forever()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            self.shutdown()

    def start_process(self, mod, fcn, *args, **kwargs):
        mod = __import__(mod, globals(), locals(), ['object'], -1)
        key = "{0}.{1}".format(mod, fcn)
        assert not key in self.processes, \
            "Process named '%s' already exists" % key
        p = Process(target=getattr(mod, fcn), name=mod, args=(None, ), kwargs=kwargs)
        self._logmessage("Process '%s' started" % key)
        p.start()
        # p.join()
        self.processes[key] = p

    def stop_process(self, key):
        self.processes[key].terminate()
        del self.processes[key]

    def get_processes(self):
        return self.processes.keys()

    def shutdown(self):
        for child in mp.active_children():
            child.terminate()
        self.server.shutdown()
        self.running = False
        print "Shutting down"

    def _logmessage(self, msg):
        print "%s: %s" % (strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server(authkey='abc')
    try:
        server.start_server()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        server.shutdown()
```

**client.py:**

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import time


class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, host='', port=50000, authkey=''):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.manager = None
        self.process = None
        self._type_id = 'get_process'
        self._authkey = authkey
        self.manager = BaseManager(address=(self.host, self.port), authkey=self._authkey)
        BaseManager.register(self._type_id)

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.manager.connect()
            self._logmessage("Connected to server")
        except:
            self._logmessage("Could not connect to server")
        self.process = getattr(self.manager, self._type_id)()

    def start_process(self, mod, fcn):
        self.process.start_process(mod, fcn)
        self._logmessage("Process '%s' started" % fcn)

    def list_processes(self):
        print self.process.get_processes()

    @property
    def connected(self):
        return self.manager._state.value == self.manager._state.STARTED

    def _logmessage(self, msg):
        print "%s: %s" % (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), msg)


def test(data):
    while True:
        print time.time()
        time.sleep(1.)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from algotrading.server.process_client import Client
    client = Client(authkey='abc')
    client.connect()
    client.start_process("algotrading.server.process_client", "test")
    client.list_processes()
```

Comment: Could you share a source ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) which allows for remote management of processes, plus automatic start/restart configurability.

Depending on your scalability and disaster-recovery needs, you may be thinking about distributing your "monitoring/trading processes" across running multiple servers. While supervisord is really only designed to manage a single machine, you could build a manager app which coordinates multiple servers, each running supervisord, via it's xml-rpc interface.

Cron or Celery could be used for your daily start/stop scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a socket server which listens to the clients and launches threads to  execute an algorithm.

I think RPC would be the simplest solution.

Some inspiration: [What is the current choice for doing RPC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python)

Comment: Sorry I might not have expressed my question clearly. I'm looking to do this with the package `multiprocessing`. I thought I could be using a `Manager` to handle this.