# Distributed system: Python 3 worker and Node.js server?

Tags: python, node.js, rpc, distributed

I'm looking to set up a distributed system where there are compute/worker machines running resource-heavy Python 3 code, and there is a single web server that serves the results of the Python computation to clients. I would very much like to write the web server in Node.js.

I've looked into using an RPC framework—specifically, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python) lead me to [ZeroRPC](http://zerorpc.dotcloud.com/), but it's not compatible with Python 3 (the main issue is that it requires `gevent`, which isn't that close to a Python 3 version yet). There doesn't seem to be another viable option for Python–Node.js RPC as far as I can tell.

In light of that, I'm open to using something other than RPC, especially since I've read that the RPC strategy hides too much from the programmer.

I'm also open to using a different language for the web server if that really makes more sense; for example, it may be much simpler from a development point of view to just use Python for the server too.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I followed the link you gave, couldn't find any mention of it not being compatible with Python 3. The source link takes you to a github repo that clearly has Python 3 related checkins. I typed `pip3 install git+https://github.com/dotcloud/zerorpc-python`, but it's got a ton of prereqs, and I don't want to wait around. Maybe it's not compatible with Python 3, but I can't see any reason to expect it to be.

Comment: @abarnert According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/zerorpc/R-b0ZSlC8sE/C4G6dE90CI8J), it depends on `gevent`, which isn't Python 3 compatible.

Comment: @dano: OK, that explains it.

Comment: Will, if `gevent` is the _only_ thing blocking you from using the library you want with Python 3, would it be reasonable for you to use a prerelease fork of `gevent` during development, with the goal of switching to the real thing when it's ready? If so, see [issue #38](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/issues/38), or google for one of the externally-maintained forks.

Comment: Of course it's a bit of a risk living on the bleeding edge. I've taken that risk a few times and gotten away with it, but it's a lot easier if you're confident you can contribute to the port if it becomes the main blocker for your deadline…

Comment: @abarnert, I think it is the only thing, except for a few lines of code that use some Python 2 syntax (for those I can just make a quick pull request to ZeroRPC). I could use a prerelease of `gevent`, though it is a bit risky. I guess that's my only real option. Thanks!

Comment: @Will: I doubt it's your only real option; this can't be the only library you could possibly use… if nothing else, you can build RPC pretty easily on top of ZeroMQ, or HTTP, or raw sockets, etc., if others hadn't already done all of those things. But ZeroRPC could easily still be your _best_ option, if, e.g., it's a great library that's a perfect fit for your project and that you've already invested time in.

Comment: One more option: If you keep the RPC-library integration and the actual code separated cleanly enough (which should be pretty simple), you could probably use something completely different now (like JSON-RPC over HTTP, which has multiple nice libraries for Node and Python) and switch to ZeroRPC later when it's official Py3-compatible.

Comment: @abarnert, Nice! I think that's probably the answer. Thank you. If you want to convert that to an official answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options here.

---

First, it sounds like you like ZeroRPC, and your only problem is that it depends on `gevent`, which is not 3.x-ready yet.

Well, `gevent` is *close* to 3.x-ready. There are a few forks of it that people are testing and even using, which you can see on [issue #38](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/issues/38). As of mid-September 2014 the one that seems to be getting the most traction is [Michal Mazurek's](https://github.com/MichalMazurek/gevent). If you're lucky, you can just do this:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/MichalMazurek/gevent
pip3 install ZeroRPC
```

Or, if `ZeroRPC` has metadata that says it's Python 2-only, you can install it from its repo the same way as `gevent`.

The down side is that none of the gevent-3.x forks are quite battle-tested yet, which is why none of them have been accepted upstream and released yet. But if you're not in a huge hurry, and willing to take a risk, there's a pretty good chance you can start with a fork today, and switch to the final version when it's released, hopefully before you've reached 1.0 yourself.

---

Second, `ZeroRPC` is certainly not the only RPC library available for either Python or Node. And most of them have a similar kind of interface for exposing methods over RPC. And, while you may ultimately need something like `ZeroMQ` for scalability or deployment reasons, you can probably use something simpler and more widespread like JSON-RPC over HTTP—which has a dozen or more Python and Node implementations—for early development, then switch to `ZeroRPC` later.

---

Third, RPC isn't exactly complicated, and binding methods to RPCs the way most libraries do isn't that hard. Making it asynchronous can be tricky, but again, for early development you can just use an easy but nonscalable solution—creating a thread for each request—and switch to something else later. (Of course that solution is only easy if your service is stateless; otherwise you're just eliminating all of your async problems and replacing them with race condition problems…)

Comment: Thanks for the elegant summary. My project is still in very early beta, and it is indeed stateless. I think I'll try the `gevent` fork you suggested, and use that if it works without much hassle; otherwise I'll probably go with option 2.

Answer (score 0):

ZeroMQ offers several transport classes, while the first two will be best suited for the case of a heterogenous RPC layer

- ipc://
- tcp://
- pgm://
- epgm://
- inproc://

ZeroMQ has ports for both systems, so will definitely serve also your projected needs.

Comment: Thanks! So you think I should write my own? I'm much more inclined to use a battle-tested library, since I'd like to minimize maintenance of the non-business-logic code—but if you think that's the best option, could you elaborate a bit on why?