# Calling methods on already running python script

Tags: python, methods

I want to call a method in running python script from another script.

For eg:

**script1.py** is continuously running. In this script there are methods.

From another **script2.py** i want to call method of **script1.py**

Comment: Are you asking about [RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python)?

Comment: 'method of script1.py': Do you want to call the method of the running instance or of a new instance?

Comment: @kums from running instance.

Comment: Why can't you just import methods of script1.py in script2.py.?

Comment: @Netro Bcoz in `script1.py` i use locking and that method also need looking. So that's my reason..

Comment: Then I believe ans suggested by @Dunes will do the trick. OR can you elaborate more with code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the multiprocessing module and a Manager object. Create a Manager object in script1.py, register the methods you want to call, and then start the server.

The module documentation has a good example of how to do all this.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers

Specific examples on how to use a remote manager can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager).

Answer (score -1):

You can import sript1.py and use function from it, because the script1.py is cached by interpreter. If I understand the question correctly.

Comment: So, if you import - `import script1`, you don't prevent to the running script1.py.