# Is there a library to interact via sockets with Python objects which are "running" on another machine?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

So suppose on some server inside of some Python environment I have an object `A`. From some client I now want to interact with this object `A` transparently as if it were in the client environment. Like when from the client I call `A.some_func(B,C)`, whatever library I'm using to do this Pickles up `(A,"some_func",B,C)`, sends it to the server via Socket, the server runs the code, and sends the client back the result. My question is, does some library to do this or something similar exist?

Clearly there are/would be many limitations, including needing everything Picklable, probably unable to do this with many of the special methods, etc..., but I'd be interested in any sort of functionality at all.

Comment: See [generator tricks for system programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/), or the builtin [xmlrpclib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html)

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python)

Comment: Ah great, thanks, "RPC" seems to be the what I was looking for, without knowing what it was called.