# How to avoid 'paramiko' which restricts me to limited python usage on remote machine?

Tags: python, paramiko, distributed-system, rpyc

I have distributed system to test (e.g. hadoop), so my test cluster has 10 to 20 machines. We have developed test automation suite which we trigger from outside of the test cluster. Being a system remotely located we are not able to leverage python modules except 'paramiko' for remote calls, as a result, we always issue a Linux commands a part of test execution.

What shall I do to leverage different python modules on remote machine? 
Is python not meant for the distributed system?

Answer (score 0):

`paramiko` definitely won't help to leverage the Python modules present on remote machines.

Python is definitely meant for distributed systems. For this, one solution I can think of is need to use **Remote Procedure Call** mechanism.

There are several modules in Python using which you can achieve RPC.

1. [XML-RPC](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html) (In-Built)
2. [RPyC](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
3. [PyRo](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/)

[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python) with multiple Python RPC solutions.

Some links with comparison between above three

- [Pyro and RPyC](https://erlerobotics.gitbooks.io/erle-robotics-python-gitbook-free/remote_procedure_call_rpc/talking_about_objects_pyro_and_rpyc.html)
- [XML-RPC vs PyRo](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/why_i_ditched_xmlrpc_in_favor.html)