# Building RPC service cluster with Python

Tags: python, rpc

I want to build a software infrastructure where a master service can dedicate work to each slave services. I want to build this using Python, any recommendations on this.
I was thinking of building it with Python RPC services which can be hosted as windows service, and then child services to communicate with the master.

Thanks

I have tried message queues so consumers would be listening to the queue so the distribution would work but i feel tcp level services might be more productive.

Comment: Does this question can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python

Comment: It helped a bit on identifying the frameworks and i have used few. Any idea would it be the best or should we consider sort of a MAP reducer type framework