# How to initialize parallel independent process within function?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

Sorry, if headline is strange. Let me explain.

Let's say there is `handler.py`:

```
import funcs
import requests

def initialize_calculate(data):
   check_data(data)
   funcs.calculate(data) # takes a lot of time like 30 minutes
   print('Calculation launched')
   requests.get('hostname', params={'func':'calculate', 'status':'launched'})
```

and here is `funcs.py`:

```
import requests

def calculate(data):
   result = make_calculations(data)
   requests.get('hostname',params={'func':'calculate', 'status':'finished', 'result':result})
```

So what I want is that handler can initialize another function no matter where, but doesn't wait until it ends, because I want to notify client-side that process is started, and when it's done this process itself will send result when it's finished.

How can I launch independent process with function calculate from `initialize_calculate`?

I want to know If it's possible without non-native libraries or frameworks.

Comment: I think what you want is remote procedure call (RPC). Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python

Comment: If third-party solution is fine for you, then you might want to take a look on celery
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/

Comment: if on the other hand you don't want a third-party for that
then you can use either `threading` `asyncio` or `multiprocessing`
check out https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/
it contains samples of each of those

Comment: Which OS? "...another function no matter where". Do you mean on another machine or just another file on the same node which should run as independent process?

Comment: @Darkonaut file.

Comment: And the parent-process should stay alive or should exit before the child is finished? Please specify your operating system.

Comment: @Darkonaut ubuntu, parent should exit before child finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wan't to use a 3rd-party lib like [daemonocle](https://pypi.org/project/daemonocle/) implementing a "well-behaved" [Unix-Daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)), you could
use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) to create an independent process. Another option would be to modify `multiprocessing.Process` to prevent auto-joining of the child when the parent exits.

---

## `subprocess.Popen()`

With [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) you start the new process with specifying commands and arguments like manually from terminal. This means you need to make `funcs.py` or another file a top-level script which parses string-arguments from stdin and then calls `funcs.calculate()` with these arguments.

I boiled your example down to the essence so we don't have to read too much code.

`funcs.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# UNIX: enable executable from terminal with: chmod +x filename
import os
import sys
import time

import psutil  # 3rd party for demo


def print_msg(msg):
    print(f"[{time.ctime()}, pid: {os.getpid()}] --- {msg}")


def calculate(data, *args):
    print_msg(f"parent pid: {psutil.Process().parent().pid}, start calculate()")
    for _ in range(int(500e6)):
        pass
    print_msg(f"parent pid: {psutil.Process().parent().pid}, end calculate()")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        calculate(*sys.argv[1:])
```

`subp_main.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# UNIX: enable executable from terminal with: chmod +x filename
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import time
    import logging
    import subprocess
    import multiprocessing as mp

    import funcs

    mp.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)

    filename = funcs.__file__
    data = ("data", 42)

    # in case filename is an executable you don't need "python" before `filename`:
    subprocess.Popen(args=["python", filename, *[str(arg) for arg in data]])
    time.sleep(1)  # keep parent alive a bit longer for demo
    funcs.print_msg(f"exiting")
```

And important for testing, run from terminal, e.g. not PyCharm-Run, because it won't show what the child prints. In the last line below you see the child process' parent-id changed to `1` because the child got adopted by systemd (Ubuntu) after the parent exited.

```
$> ./subp_main.py
[Fri Oct 23 20:14:44 2020, pid: 28650] --- parent pid: 28649, start calculate()
[Fri Oct 23 20:14:45 2020, pid: 28649] --- exiting
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
$> [Fri Oct 23 20:14:54 2020, pid: 28650] --- parent pid: 1, end calculate()
```

---

## `class OrphanProcess(multiprocessing.Process)`

If you search for something more convenient, well you can't use the high-level `multiprocessing.Process` as is, because it doesn't let the parent process exit *before* the child, as you asked for. Regular child-processes are either joined (awaited) or terminated (if you set the `daemon`-flag for `Process`) when the parent shuts down. This still happens within Python. Note that the `daemon`-flag doesn't make a process a *Unix*-Daemon. The naming is a somewhat frequent source of [confusion](https://bugs.python.org/issue5906).

I subclassed `multiprocessing.Process` to switch the auto-joining off and spend some time with the source and observing if [zombies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) might become an issue. Because the modification turns off automatic joining in the parent, I recommend using "forkserver" as start-method for new processes on Unix (always a good idea if the parent is already multi-threaded) to prevent zombie-children from sticking around as long the parent is still running. When the parent process terminates, its child-zombies get eventually [reaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) by systemd/init. Running `multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()` shows everything shutting down cleanly, so nothing seems broken so far.

Consider this approach experimental, but it's probably a lot safer than using raw `os.fork()` to re-invent part of the extensive `multiprocessing` machinery, just to add this one feature. For error-handling in the child, write a try-except block and log to file.

`orphan.py`

```
import multiprocessing.util
import multiprocessing.process as mpp
import multiprocessing as mp

__all__ = ['OrphanProcess']


class OrphanProcess(mp.Process):
    """Process which won't be joined by parent on parent shutdown."""
    def start(self):
        super().start()
        mpp._children.discard(self)

    def __del__(self):
        # Finalizer won't `.join()` the child because we discarded it,
        # so here last chance to reap a possible zombie from within Python.
        # Otherwise systemd/init will reap eventually.
        self.join(0)
```

`orph_main.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# UNIX: enable executable from terminal with: chmod +x filename
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import time
    import logging
    import multiprocessing as mp
    from orphan import OrphanProcess
    from funcs import print_msg, calculate

    mp.set_start_method("forkserver")
    mp.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)

    p = OrphanProcess(target=calculate, args=("data", 42))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print_msg(f"exiting")
```

Again test from terminal to get the child print to stdout. When the shell appears to be hanging after everything was printed over the second prompt, hit enter to get a new prompt. The parent-id stays the same here because the parent, from the OS-point of view, is the forkserver-process, not the initial main-process for orph_main.py.

```
$> ./orph_main.py
[INFO/MainProcess] created temp directory /tmp/pymp-bd75vnol
[INFO/OrphanProcess-1] child process calling self.run()
[Fri Oct 23 21:18:29 2020, pid: 30998] --- parent pid: 30997, start calculate()
[Fri Oct 23 21:18:30 2020, pid: 30995] --- exiting
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
$> [Fri Oct 23 21:18:38 2020, pid: 30998] --- parent pid: 30997, end calculate()
[INFO/OrphanProcess-1] process shutting down
[DEBUG/OrphanProcess-1] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/OrphanProcess-1] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/OrphanProcess-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
```

Comment: Here `subprocess.Popen()` can we wait its output to return and continue after subprocess is completed?

Comment: @alper I think you're looking for [`Popen.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait).

Comment: Thanks `      output, error = p.communicate(); p.wait()` was what I was looking for. On `orph_main.py` and `subp_main.py` is it recommended to keep `imports` inside the `__main__` or could we use them on top of the file

Comment: @alper Sure you can put the imports at the top of the file. I just chose to put them below there to emphasize that I only need them loaded when the file gets run as top-level script, which here is the only use case that makes sense since there are no definitions above `'__main__'` one might want to import from _another_ file.

Comment: Would it be possible to send bytes variable inside the `*args` instead of string? I am having `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int` error

Comment: I think we have to use `*_args` instead of `args` name . `_args[idx]` return valid valud but `args` returns `data = 'funcname'
_args = ("")`. I had to do `_args = make_tuple(str(args))` which can fetch items as _args[0] and so on

Answer (score 1):

you may use [`Process` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) from `multiprocessing` module to do that.

Here is an example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import requests

def calculate(data):
    result = make_calculations(data)
    requests.get('hostname',params={'func':'calculate', 'status':'finished', 'result':result})

def initialize_calculate(data):
    check_data(data)
    p = Process(target=calculate, args=(data,))
    p.start()
    print('Calculation launched')
    requests.get('hostname', params={'func':'calculate', 'status':'launched'})
```

Comment: It works in __name__=='__main__'. Else it throws :RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase. I can't call initilize_calculate from another module. But your solutions is the closest to what i seek

Comment: I am getting following two errors: `NameError: name 'check_data' is not defined` and `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'hostname': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://hostname?
`

Comment: @alper the answer is written based on the snippet the OP has given. (I.e, it is assumed that you have a custom function named `check_data` that you have created and `hostname` is your `URL` - you are supposed to replace that)

Comment: Can main process wait subprocess for `calculate ` to finish and continue when the subprocess return?