# Run a function (in a new thread) on a subprocess that is already running

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have some expensive long-running functions that I'd like to run on multiple cores.  This is easy to do with multiprocessing.  But I will also need to periodically run a function that calculates a value based on the state (global variables) of a specific process.  I think this should be possible by simply spawning a thread on the subprocess.

Here's a simplified example.  Please suggest how I can call `procces_query_state()`.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def process_runner(x: int):
    global xx
    xx = x
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        xx += 1  # actually an expensive calculation

def process_query_state() -> int:
    y = xx * 2 # actually an expenseive calculation
    return y

def main():
    processes = {}
    for x in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.get_context('spawn').Process(target=process_runner, args=(x,))
        p.start()
        processes[x] = p
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(processes[3].process_query_state()) # this doesn't actually work

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: as for me when process runs `process_runner()` then it can't run any other function. And if you need some value from process then you should use queue to send it to main process.

Comment: I think you expect too much. `Process` is not `RPC` (Remote Procedure Call) - [What is the current choice for doing RPC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879971/what-is-the-current-choice-for-doing-rpc-in-python). It would need something more. Process would need one thread to get messages from other processes and others threads to runs functions at the same time. With `Process` you could use `queue` to send message to other process - and inside `process_runner` it would have to check if there is message in queue and run `process_query_state` and send result using also `queue

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. `Process` is not `RPC` (`Remote Procedure Call`) and you can't execute other function `process_query_state` from main process. You can only use `queue` to send some information to other process - but this process has to periodically check if there is new message.
2. `Process` can run only one function so it would stop one function when it get message to run other function or it would have to run `threads` on new `processes` to run many functions at the same time.

**EDIT:** It may give other problem - if two functions will work at the same time on the same data then one can change value before other will use old value and this can create wrong results.

---

I created example which uses queues to send message to `process_runner`, and it periodically check if there is message and run `process_query_state`, and it send result back to main process.

Main process wait for result from selected porcess - it blocks code - but if you want to work with more processes then it would have to make it more complex.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def process_query_state():
    y = xx * 2 # actually an expenseive calculation
    return y

def process_runner(x: int, queue_in, queue_out):
    global xx
    xx = x

    # reverse direction
    q_in = queue_out
    q_out = queue_in
    
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        xx += 1  # actually an expensive calculation

        # run other function - it will block main calculations 
        # but this way it will use correct `xx` (other calculations will not change it)
        if not q_in.empty():
            if q_in.get() == 'run':
                result = process_query_state()
                q_out.put(result)
                
def main():
    processes = {}
    for x in range(4):
        ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')
        q_in  = ctx.Queue()
        q_out = ctx.Queue()
        p = ctx.Process(target=process_runner, args=(x, q_in, q_out))
        p.start()
        processes[x] = (p, q_in, q_out)
        
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        q_in  = processes[3][1]
        q_out = processes[3][2]
        q_out.put('run')
        
        # non blocking version
        #if not q_in.empty():
        #    print(q_in.get())
        
        # blocking version
        print(q_in.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```